# unable to take screenshot of mouseover in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, screenshot

I am trying to take screenshot of sub menu which happens on hovering in selenium using `TakesScreenshot`. But this is not working. Screenshot is taken but sub menu is not present in the image.
I have also tried using implicit wait after hover, but nothing worked.
Please suggest a method to capture screenshot of the sub menu.

```
contactUs.hoverHM();
screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) PageFactoryBase.getSharedWebDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
```

Comment: can u please provide body of hoverHM?

Comment: public void hoverHM()
    {
        builder.moveToElement(getSharedWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='brand section']/ul/li[@class='active hasflyout']"))).perform();

    }

Comment: Can u try to move to the element with robot class and then take screenshot? Also please check whether manually going to hover and then taking scrrenshot and pasting it to paint shows u that menu? Webdriver picks everything from rendered dom so it won't include any extra windows etc. Might be it is possible that ur menu is under a iframe or frame or modal dialog.

Comment: Thanks vivek. I tried using robot.mousemove() and its working fine for me now.

Comment: ..great it worked for u...happy to help... !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for answering on this thread. 
I am able to take screenshot using robot as suggested by Vivek.

builder.moveToElement(getSharedWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='brand section']/ul/li[@class='active hasflyout']"))).perform();
Robot robot = new Robot();

Point point;

point = getSharedWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='brand section']/ul/li[@class='active hasflyout']")).getLocation();
        int x = point.getX();
        int y = point.getY();
           robot.mouseMove(x,y);

In ideal case, either perform() or mouseMove() should be used. But somehow in my case, i had to use both the functions.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me. I am pretty sure it will work for you.

```
            _driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseover_mouseout");
            _driver.SwitchTo().Frame(_driver.FindElement(By.Id("iframeResult")));
            Actions builder = new Actions(_driver);
            builder.MoveToElement(_driver.FindElement(By.TagName("p"))).Build().Perform();
            var screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)_driver).GetScreenshot();
            var filename = new StringBuilder("D:\\");
            filename.Append(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH_mm_ss dd-MM-yyyy" + " "));
            filename.Append("test");
            filename.Append(".png");
            screenshot.SaveAsFile(filename.ToString(), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

After hovering mouse on the text, it turns yellow and below is the screen shot that I took.
[image: Screen shot that I took]

Answer (score 0):

Below is another approach where you can use '*Print screen*' Key in your Test code and get the image from the clipboard in the system.
 What is have done is used KeyEvent '*PRTSC*' to get the Image into the system clipboard and then get the system clipboard to write it to a file. I hope it will also copy the mouseover.

```
Robot rob = new Robot();

rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);

Clipboard clip = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

Transferable content = clip.getContents(null);

BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage)content.getTransferData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);

ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("D:\\test.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same scenario but for `clickAndHold` for hover skin. It worked for me with the help of `Actions` as below:

```
WebElement elm = driver.findElement(By.id("btn1"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action act = builder.clickAndHold(elm).build();
act.perform();
try {
     File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
     FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\Img\\screenshot.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
act = builder.release(elm).build();
act.perform();
```

You can instead replace `clickAndHold` with `moveToElement` Mouse hover the element. take the screenshot then release the element or move away from it.